# Rearrange rows from first row with R

Tags: r, row, na

I have a data frame like this,

```
user_name1     user_name2        user_name3
0                Alex              0
0                  0               0
0                  0             Jacob
0
                  Lee             Mark
John               0              Kevin
```

I want to rearrange this in this way ignoring 0 or any NA values,

```
user_name1     user_name2        user_name3
    John          Alex              Jacob
    0             Lee                Mark
    0              0                 Kevin
    0              0                   0
    0              0                   0
    0              0                   0
```

noticeable that, row numbers will be unchanged.

```
user_name1 <- c(0,0,0,0, "", "John")
user_name2 <- c("Alex", 0,0, "", "Lee",0)
user_name3 <- c(0,0, "Jacob", "",  "Mark", "Kevin")
df<- data.frame(user_name1, user_name2, user_name3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A decreasing `sort` works well:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, sort, decreasing=TRUE)
df
#  user_name1 user_name2 user_name3
#1       John        Lee       Mark
#2          0       Alex      Kevin
#3          0          0      Jacob
#4          0          0          0
#5          0          0          0
```

**update**

If there are blank spaces of `NA` values in the data you can fix them first then run the above code:

```
#Example with NA and blank ""
  user_name1 user_name2 user_name3
1          0       Alex          0
2          0          0          0
3          0          0      Jacob
4          0                  <NA>
5                   Lee       Mark
6       John          0      Kevin
```

First coerce values to zero, then `sort`:

```
df[df=="" | is.na(df)] <- 0
df[] <- lapply(df, sort, decreasing=TRUE)
#  user_name1 user_name2 user_name3
#1       John        Lee       Mark
#2          0       Alex      Kevin
#3          0          0      Jacob
#4          0          0          0
#5          0          0          0
#6          0          0          0
```

**data**

```
user_name1 <- c(0,0,0,0,"", "John")
user_name2 <- c("Alex", 0,0,"", "Lee",0)
user_name3 <- c(0,0, "Jacob", NA, "Mark", "Kevin")
df<- data.frame(user_name1, user_name2, user_name3,
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: sorry, it still creating error for me. because original data frame has some missing values and NA values as well. `user_name1 <- c("John", <no values at all>, NA, 0, 0)` thanks for your help. Trying to figure out solution based on your suggestion

Comment: Can you be more specific about "no values at all"? Please add actual data from your original

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Can you see my edited question now? the main data frame I am working has some thing like this.

Comment: Instead of editing the table in the post. Add the correct code. The space you create can mean different things in actual code. Please add "code" that summarises the variability, not just an added space in the question.

Comment: You probably need to add a `na.last = TRUE` since by default, `sort` will remove `NA`s (check `sort(c(0, "a", NA))`)

Comment: @docendodiscimus I just cleaned it along with the blanks simultaneously

Comment: Thanks, I am new in R, so little slow in understanding. I have also edited the code. going to follow you.

Comment: I added an example with blanks and NA's

Comment: Thank  you @PierreLafortune

Comment: Thank you @docendodiscimus :)

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df[df=="" | is.na(df)] <- 0
df <- df %>% mutate_each(funs(sort(.,decreasing = TRUE))) 

#      user_name1 user_name2 user_name3
#1       John        Lee       Mark
#2          0       Alex      Kevin
#3          0          0      Jacob
#4          0          0          0
#5          0          0          0
```

Comment: I get an error on this `Error: wrong result size (5), expected 6 or 1`. Try it on the data I provided.

Comment: No, it is working fine. `library(dplyr);
df %>% mutate_each(funs(sort(.,decreasing = TRUE)))`

Comment: with `NA` values we will have to add `na.last=TRUE`

Comment: What mistake? I don't understand, sorry.

Comment: nope @akrun, you did not make mistake, it is working fine and excellent. you guys are genius

Comment: @akrun , as I have changed the data frame with null values, instead of your previous code, this edited code will work now. hope you wont mind.

Comment: @bipu I approved your edits.   Thanks for doing the extra step and plus one to you as well.

Comment: Why not just treat every answer on its own merits. Who cares about the petty stuff? That kind of attitude is ruining SO